# Minimum norm of analytic function may not be achieved on the boundary of its domain

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, optimization

I need to show that the minimum modulus of an analytic function may not be achieved on the boundary of its domain. I'm stuck with this question, would appreciate if someone could help me with it. I don't even know where to start to proof.

Comment: $z\ \ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: $f(z)=z$? I think the domain of $f$ does not have a boundary in this case.

Comment: But it's a restricted domain. I need to prove that there does not exist a function $f(z)$ such that it's modulus achieves a minimum on the boundary of the domain of $f$.

Comment: If we consider $f(z) =\frac{1}{z}$, $\lim\limits_{z\to\infty} \implies \left| f \right|\to 0$. So doesn't the modulus of this function reach the minimum value in its modulus when $z$ approaches the boundary of the domain?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with restricting the domain of a function.  In any case, if the domain has no boundary, then it is vacuously true that the minimum is not achieved on the boundary.

Comment: @EricWofsey What do you think about my example above?

Comment: $f(z) = 1/z$ but on what domain ?

Comment: @user1952009 Say, $z\ne 0, |z|\le 1000$.

Comment: a [domain is a connected open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_(mathematical_analysis)), so you mean $U = \{0 < |z| < 1000\}$ which is open and connected, and $f(z) = 1/z$ is analytic on $U$

Comment: Right. But I think I gave a counterexample. The boundary of $U$ is at $|z|=1000$.